# VO issue over object in flex fusioncharts

Tags: fusioncharts

when I use VO instead of Object in the fusionCharts loader function I get the "set"
()attribute empty.

MY CODE:

```
[Bindable]
private var chartColl:ArrayCollection;

private function chartDetails():void
{
   var chartColl:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
   for (var j:int =0;j<uniqueData.length;j++)
   {
      var obj:ChartVO=new ChartVO();
      obj.label=String(uniqueData.getItemAt(j));
      var count:int=0;

      for(var i:int=0;i<getPopulation.length;i++)
      {
         if(String(uniqueData.getItemAt(j))== getPopulation.getItemAt(i).country)
         {
                count=count+getPopulation.getItemAt(i).count;
         }
      }

      obj.value=count;
      chartColl.addItem(obj);                               
  } 
  fc.FCData(chartColl);
  fc.FCRender();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set 'value' property too along with 'label' property.

Please check setting debug mode the resultant XML.

Also make sure you are building proper ArrayCollection format as per chart type.

The data format for each type/group of chart is listed in these links:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/create_single_array.html 
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/create_multi_array.html
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/create_stacked_array.html
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/create_combi_array.html
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/create_plot_array.html

List of chart types/groups are here:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/introduction_chartTypes.html

For further information on mapping of data from FusionCharts native XML format to ArrayCollection read:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/xml_mapping_singleSeries.html
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/xml_mapping_multiSeries.html
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/xml_mapping_plot.html

Comment: I get proper Arraycollection format when Object is used,but when i use VO of the same I get the FCData as empty parameters.